# preg_replace to add foundation reveal to wordpress image links

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

Was wondering if someone can give me a hand using preg_replace in Wordpress to change the way links to images function.

So currently with mootools lazyload enabled I've got it spitting out:

```
<a href='http://localhost:8080/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/2014-11-26-20.52.53.jpg'><img width="150" height="150" src="http://localhost:8080/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/2014-11-26-20.52.53-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="2014-11-26 20.52.53" /></a>
```

Ideally I'd like it to all thumbnail links load in a Foundation Reveal Modal with code like this:

```
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="2014-11-26-20.52.53"> 
<img src="http://localhost:8080/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/2014-11-26-20.52.53-150x150.jpg">
</a>

<div id="2014-11-26-20.52.53" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
<img src="http://localhost:8080/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/2014-11-26-20.52.53.jpg">
<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

Any suggestions? I've tried butchering some similar code - but preg_replace isn't the easiest syntax to learn.

Comment: why do you want to remove the absolute url? wordpress adds this automatically, when you move it to another url, you'll set the url of the site and it'll display correctly.

Comment: Ah that was just to remove the http://localhost:8080/ url as I'nm working on a vagrant at the moment and stackoverflow was complaining about using that in a path.

Comment: Ah lets me do it if it's in code nm!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I'm close:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'addreveal', 12);
add_filter('get_comment_text', 'addreveal');

function addreveal ($content){   
    global $post;
    $pattern = "/<a(.*?)href=('|\")([^>]*).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)('|\")(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>/i";
    $replacement = '<a$1href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">$7</a> <div id="myModal"       class="reveal-modal" data-reveal> <img src="$3.$4"> <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>   </div> ';
    $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
    return $content;
```

}

However I'm a bit confused with the $7 variable - I'd like to split this by / and make the filename without the extension the data-reveal-id. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me after some minor tweaks for Foundation 6

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'addreveal', 12 );
add_filter( 'get_comment_text', 'addreveal' );

function addreveal ($content) {
    global $post;
    $pattern = "/<a(.*?)href=('|\")([^>]*).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)('|\")(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>/i";
    $replacement = '<a$1href="#" data-open="full">$7</a>
    <div id="full" class="full-image reveal" data-reveal>
        <div class="modal-container">
            <img src="$3.$4">
            <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close reveal" type="button"></button>
        </div>
    </div>';
    $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
    return $content;
}
```